# Why Xcode doesn't show up inherited methods in subclass's implementation file in cocos2d projects?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode5

I use cocos2d 2.1.0 version to learn gamedevelopment for iOS and the latest version of Xcode.
When I create new subclasses, for example:
`JTObject` from `CCNode` class, add `initWithSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite` (I add this method in public .h file too), and then new sublclass from `JTObject` - `JTTankObject`.
Xcode doesn't show up this  `initWithSprite:(CCSprite*)sprite` method in `JTTankObject.m` file, as it is supposed to do with inherited methods. So I need to copy and paste it.

And even more, in subclassed files highlighting of code doesn't work too.
Xcode uses highlighting for data types only after deleting and creating this file multiple times or after rebuilding project more than one time. 
And I know, that not only I've faced with this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't show up this method"? I often have problems with Xcode and syntax highlighting not working properly, closing and opening Xcode usually solves the problem. By the way if you are learning cocos2d you may want to use version 3.x as this is the latest version.

Comment: So this problem is connected to Xcode? not to cocos2d?
About 3.x version - the majority of literature is dedicated to the previous versions of cocos2d.

Comment: Inherited methods are never automatically created in .m files, you always need to add any method you want to override manually.

Comment: It's a feature that Apple could add, for example, to optionally show inherited methods in grayed-out text or something. But this could be pretty confusing if not implemented correctly.